# Cancelling NSOperationQueue from within NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

I have some iPhone SDK 4.0 code which initializes an `NSOperationQueue` and then adds three classes (`ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC`) to run one after the other. `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` are all sub-classes of `NSOperation`.

The relevant code is included below.

```
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
ClassC *classC = [[ClassC alloc] init];

[classB addDependency:classA];
[classC addDependency:classB];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[queue addOperation:classA];
[queue addOperation:classB];
[queue addOperation:classC];

[classA release];
[classB release];
[classC release];
[queue release];
```

The reason for the dependencies is because `classB` should only run if `classA` completes its operation successfully. Likewise, `classC` should only run if `classB` completes successfully.

At the moment I am having difficulty figuring out how to prevent, for example, `classB` from running if `classA` does not complete successfully. Continuing with this example, I was thinking of somehow evoking `[NSOperationQueue cancelAllOperations]` from within `classA` but I don't know how to get a handle on the parent `NSOperationQueue` from within `classA` (which is an `NSOperation` sub-class). This was just my initial thought, so I would be open to any other better suggestions for achieving the same outcome!

There is conditional code within each of the classes to determine whether they have completed properly - at the moment they are just NSLogging "Success" or "Fail" to the Console for debugging purposes. In a perfect world I would just like to be able to replace the `NSLog(@"Fail")` statement in each class with some code which will stop all of the other classes in the NSOperationQueue from running.

Any suggestions would be most welcome (and appreciated).

Comment: What do you mean by "does not complete successfully". Does the operation encounter an error or is the operation not completing at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a property in classA :

```
@property (readonly) BOOL completedSucessfully;
```

and set this to YES at the end of classA's main method.

Then, just check it at the start of classB.

```
- (void)main {
    if (NO == [[dependencies objectAtIndex:0] completedSucessfully])
        return;
```

Now, classB will just stop if classA reports failure.

NB You will probably need more error checking that in the example above i.e. making sure that you have dependencies, checking that it's the correct class etc.

```
- (void)main {
    for (id *temp in [self dependencies])
        if ([temp isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]])
            if (NO == [(ClassA *)temp finishedSucessfully])
                return;
```

Comment: This design has problems. The [dependencies objectAtIndex:0] could be nil.

Comment: read the second code snippet ;) the first was just included to be quickly readable, the second is the one I'd actually use.

Comment: what happens if ClassA is removed from dependencies by operationqueue or another controller object? I would use notifications from the operations, MYOperationDidSucceed and MYOperationDidFailWithError. Add the next operation to the queue only on success, clean up (undoManager) any mess left behind in the event of a failure

Comment: I'd argue that removing a dependency from an operation is telling the operation that you don't care about that result anymore! However, if you're worried about that happening notifications would work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, if speed is not an issue, you can work synchronously. Else you can use:

```
[selector:@selctor(StartB) waitUntilTaskComplete:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

After viewing the WWDC 2015 session on advanced NSOperation techniques (highly recommended) I started using them in-depth in my own code.  Here are some suggestions to achieve this

1. From within an NSOperation you can call [self currentQueue] to get "The operation queue that started the operation or nil if the queue could not be determined."  You could then call cancelAllOperations on the returned queue.  Empirically I have had difficulty using this approach because if you explicitly run code on the main queue, have code in a closures/block, or call a third party library, then the queue returned may not be the initial queue at all.  In that situation calling cancelAllOperations will not result in the expected behavior - instead you are canceling the operations on a different queue.
2. Subclass NSOperation to include a property for the initial NSOperationQueue and subclass NSOperationQueue to set the property when the operation is added to the queue.  Then call cancelAllOperations on self.initialQueue.  This is the approach I'm using and works across all the scenarios mentioned above.
3. Instead of canceling all operations at the queue level, you can call the operation "cancel" method and finish your operation.  If your operations have been written to conform to Apple's operation guidelines, they all check isCancelled when starting, and abort processing if true.  It's a subtle difference:  when you cancel the queue operations, any operations that haven't been started will not be started at all.  When you set the operations to isCancelled, subsequent operations are started but (should) finish shortly there after.  This allows scenarios where later operations might perform some cleanup, error handling, or user notification.

Comment: `self.currentQueue` isn't a property of NSOperation?

Comment: It is needed because there is a difference between the "initial" queue and the "current" queue.  If you have an operation that calls a third party library, or runs code in a closure/block, that code may actually execute on a queue other than the initial one.  At least, that's my experience (especially with the Facebook SDK).